# trouble finding wordpress home page

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble trying to find the homepage for a wordpress site. I am not the original developer on this page. I have looked and looked for the page in pages, portfolio, posts, etc. The settings in reading is set to the default blog, when I go to appearance->customize->Static front page, It is set to latest posts. I was told by another employee that the previous developer was editing a file so I am wondering where this Blog file would be at? Also I am running the striking theme and inside the admin panel for the Blog section it said the page is set for news, however when I go to the news page it is completely empty. Does anyone have any ideas? I am not a big wordpress guy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The striking theme homepage is created by going to the admin->Striking->Homepage->Homepage Content

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the theme being used(striking?) you should be able to find all custom files in

```
wp-content/themes/striking/
```

I'd check home.php or index.php

Hopefully that gives you a decent starting point.

Comment: in my database under wp_options  there is a row `striking_homepage` which contains all the html for the homepage but if I change one little thing it crashes the entire homepage for some reason. I have looked in the suggested place in your answer but found nothing I did find home.php but it looks like a normal php page.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point is to look in Settings > Reading and check Front page displays.

What does it say?

Also have you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page ? May be useful.

Comment: That was stated in the question I found the problem though thanks for the suggestion